# Multiple select with conditions from each table

Tags: mysql

So I have the tables
ip_clients, ip_invoice_items, ip_invoice_item_amounts, ip_invoices, ip_payments, ip_tax_rates.

#### Structures:

```
| ip_clients  | ip_invoice_items     | ip_invoice_item_amounts |
| ----------- | -------------------- | ----------------------- |
| client_id   | item_id              | item_amount_id          |
| client_name | invoice_id           | item_id                 |
|             | item_quantity        | item_total              |
|             | item_price           | item_discount           |
|             | item_discount_amount |                         |
| ----------- | -------------------- | ----------------------- |

| ip_invoices       | ip_payments    | ip_tax_rates     |
| ----------------- | -------------- | ---------------- |
| invoice_id        | payment_id     | tax_rate_percent |
| user_id           | invoice_id     |                  |
| invoice_status_id | payment_amount |                  |
| ----------------- | -------------- | ---------------- |
```

#### What is stored in Tables and Cells:

**ip_clients**: where the clients are stored

```
client_id: client unique id
client_name: the client name
```

**ip_invoice_items**: where the invoice items are stored

```
item_id: unique item id
invoice_id: unique invoice id from ip_invoices
item_quantity: the item's quantity
item_price: the item's cost stored as double example (11.29)
item_discount_amount: the item's discount stored as double example (5.19)
```

**ip_invoice_item_amounts**: where payments are stored

```
item_amount_id: the unique the item's id
item_id: the unique item's id from ip_invoice_items
item_total: the total item cost is stored as double (50.01)
item_discount: the item discount is stored as double (30.49)
```

**ip_invoices**: the invoice id and the user id

```
invoice_id: the unique invoice id
user_id: the unique user id from ip_clients
invoice_status_id: if this cell has number 4 means its paid
```

**ip_payments**: the payment id the invoice id and the payment amount

```
payment_id: the unique payment id
invoice_id: the unique invoice id from ip_invoice
payment_amount: the amount paid is stored as double (100.00)
```

**ip_tax_rates**: contains the tax percent number

```
tax_rate_percent: contains single number
```

#### How it works:

1. I create invoices with selected items amount and cost
2. I insert payments from clients to close the invoices.

#### Question

I want to know the balance of the client how many money he has to pay
I would like to get as result the **client name** and hes **current debt (balance)** only if he has open invoices (he owns money).
So the query should be able to see what invoice id's has been paid and not count those amounts and in balance result should be added the tax percentage.

I am sorry that I can not make it I am stuck and I do not even know if I explained it correctly since it is to complicated for me I ask help

here is the structure https://pastebin.com/c3iYNMkq

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: To ask an On Topic questions, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: RiggsFolly I have tried alot of queries without success and most of times they took more than a minute to get results I tried with inner join outer I have no idea where to start with from what table I have to start in such complex database?

Comment: How is invoice_status_id working?

Comment: when the invoice created there is an option to select if the status is paid or not paid its totaly manual option by hand but when invoice_status_id has the value 4 means the invoice paid else if its 0-1-2-3 is not paid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's find out which are the open invoices of a certain client with the debt for each:

```
select ip_clients.client_id, sum(ip_invoice_items.item_quantity * ip_invoice_items.item_price) - sum(ip_payments.payment_amount) as debt
from ip_clients
join ip_invoices
on ip_clients.client_id = ip_invoices.user_id
join ip_invoice_items
on ip_invoices.invoice_id = ip_invoice_items.invoice_id
join ip_payments
on ip_invoices.invoice_id = ip_payments.invoice_id
group by ip_clients.client_id, ip_invoices.invoice_id
having sum(ip_invoice_items.item_quantity * ip_invoice_items.item_price) - sum(ip_payments.payment_amount) > 0
```

Now, let's use this knowledge to get the total balance:

```
select ip_clients.client_name, sum(debt) as balance
from ip_clients
join
(
select ip_clients.client_id, sum(ip_invoice_items.item_quantity * ip_invoice_items.item_price) - sum(ip_payments.payment_amount) as debt
from ip_clients
join ip_invoices
on ip_clients.client_id = ip_invoices.user_id
join ip_invoice_items
on ip_invoices.invoice_id = ip_invoice_items.invoice_id
join ip_payments
on ip_invoices.invoice_id = ip_payments.invoice_id
group by ip_clients.client_id, ip_invoices.invoice_id
having sum(ip_invoice_items.item_quantity * ip_invoice_items.item_price) - sum(ip_payments.payment_amount) > 0
) t
on ip_clients.client_id = t.client_id
group by ip_clients.client_id, ip_clients.client_name
```

I am not 100% sure I understood your business model, so you might polish slightly the query, but you get the idea.

Comment: I would never imagine such big query, I really thank you for the time, I tested this query it returns null in both cases but seems to be excactly what I want

Comment: @WolfBillaros probably I did not quite understand your business model, nevertheless, this is a point where you can start working from and the actual distance between this one and the desired one should not be too great.

Comment: I think I found the problem with this query if I got it all correct, first of all its 2 queries, the first one gives a dept and the second one with some changes gives me data
first query
1 -12.7700
1 -79.5400
1 -120.5500
1 -63.9500

Second query
Client 1 -276.8100
Client 2 -276.8100

so the first query gives only client 1 and hes dept while query 2 takes clients 1 and places the dept of client 1 in all the results, it should result to client1 and client1-dept, client2 and client2-dept.
lets hope I am understandable, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @WolfBillaros I could not really understand your point, but I am happy you figured the problem out.

Comment: you can join https://demo.invoiceplane.com/index.php/sessions/login to see the demo on how it works. It is free on github and I want to modify some things one of them is this in general that I want to print each client with the balance(dept) he owns in the first topic I added some SQL parts that may help

Comment: I did not figured it out yet I am working on it still, if you want to help me further you're welcome.

Comment: @WolfBillaros unfortunately I have no time to check out how the system works myself by testing the page. If you could describe your business model, the way it currently works and the desired improvement, I would gladly help you.